# Python/Pandas: assign a value to a column based on multiple column/row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry if this has been asked, but I can't find an answer after hours of searching.  I have a dataframe containing multiple stock tickers, three rows each of each of the same stock.  I used a groupby to get 20, 50, and 200 day moving averages.  Now I have a study column that denote which Mov Avg described in the neighboring "CloseAvgs" column.  I created empty columns for the three Mov Avg types and want to fill those in for each stock ticker.  Here's what the first portion of my DF looks like:

```
  Ticker        Close          Low         High    Study    CloseAvgs SMA 20 SMA 50 SMA 200
0   AAPL   131.985001   130.229996   132.630005  SMA 200   102.335087
1   AAPL   131.985001   130.229996   132.630005   SMA 50   122.444300
2   AAPL   131.985001   130.229996   132.630005   SMA 20   129.470750
0   AMZN  3185.360107  3142.475586  3186.724121  SMA 200  2909.497447
1   AMZN  3185.360107  3142.475586  3186.724121   SMA 50  3169.752793
2   AMZN  3185.360107  3142.475586  3186.724121   SMA 20  3201.456482
0    CRM   221.590500   219.220001   222.320007  SMA 200   209.404753
1    CRM   221.590500   219.220001   222.320007   SMA 50   236.049410
2    CRM   221.590500   219.220001   222.320007   SMA 20   223.208023
```

I am trying to assign the SMA 20, 50, and 200 for each ticker into the blank columns to the right via this command (I left off the SMA 50 and SMA 200 for brevity):

```
        for study in finaldf:
            finaldf.loc['SMA 20'] = finaldf[finaldf['CloseAvgs']('Study') == 'SMA 20']

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

It is fine if the result goes into all 3 of the rows for each ticker symbol, as I will be dropping the other 2 rows.  Is there a way for me to get this working?  Thank you!

Edit: Here is what I'm looking for in the final DF.  You can see, I just want to grab the SMA20, SMA50, and SMA200 values from each ticker (based on the CloseAvgs column and corresponding Study column for each) and place them in the appropriate columns for each stock.  I removed a couple columns that weren't needed.  These SMA columns are currently blank, and I want them filled in as follows:

```
  Ticker        Close   Study    CloseAvgs SMA 20    SMA 50     SMA 200
0   AAPL   131.985001   SMA 200  102.3350  129.4707  122.4443   102.3350
1   AAPL   131.985001   SMA 50   122.4443  129.4707  122.4443   102.3350
2   AAPL   131.985001   SMA 20   129.4707  129.4707  122.4443   102.3350
0   AMZN  3185.360107   SMA 200  2909.497  3201.456  3169.752   2909.497
1   AMZN  3185.360107   SMA 50   3169.752  3201.456  3169.752   2909.497
2   AMZN  3185.360107   SMA 20   3201.456  3201.456  3169.752   2909.497
0    CRM   221.590500   SMA 200  209.4047  223.2080  236.0494   209.4047 
1    CRM   221.590500   SMA 50   236.0494  223.2080  236.0494   209.4047 
2    CRM   221.590500   SMA 20   223.2080  223.2080  236.0494   209.4047
```

Comment: `finaldf['CloseAvgs']` gives a series, and `finaldf['CloseAvgs']('Study')` is you treating the series as a function and trying to call it with `('Study')`. That's why you get the error. Next time you get errors you can try googling the error message i.e. `TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable`

Comment: Can you give an example output? It's not clear what you want

Comment: Ok, I edited the original question, adding what I'm trying to accomplish.  Not sure if it's possible.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is to divide the data frame by price and moving average, delete duplicate rows for price, transform the moving average by pivoting, and combine each with a stock.

```
df_index = df.loc[:,['Ticker','Close','Low','High']]
df_index.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
df_sma = df.loc[:,['Ticker','Study','CloseAvgs']]
df_sma = pd.pivot(df_sma, index='Ticker', columns='Study', values='CloseAvgs')
df_sma.reset_index(inplace=True)
final_df = df_index.merge(df_sma, on='Ticker', how='inner')

final_df
    Ticker  Close   Low     High    SMA 20  SMA 200     SMA 50
0   AAPL    131.985001  130.229996  132.630005  129.470750  102.335087  122.444300
1   AMZN    3185.360107     3142.475586     3186.724121     3201.456482     2909.497447     3169.752793
2   CRM     221.590500  219.220001  222.320007  223.208023  209.404753  236.049410
```

Comment: Awesome!  That was exactly what I was looking for... Much appreciated!